# Chartkick: Arel::Visitors::UnsupportedVisitError in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chartkick

I am using the [Chartkick gem](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick) to design a dashboard graph for a Ruby on Rails application.

I tried to use the **multiple series** chart function to display a **true and false** chart for the payment data which is a boolean (true and false) by using the code below.

```
<%= line_chart Donation.group(:payment).group_by_day(:created_at).count, colors: ["#342F49", "#FB4D00" ] %>
```

While, it was showing the chart for the payment, the label for **false** was not showing, it was only displaying the label for **true**. I have attached a screenshot of the issue.

[image: Screenshot of the label not displaying false]

So I decided to add a **name** option to the **multiple series** chart function based on the chartkick gem documentation in order to show the both labels for true and false by using the code below

```
<%= line_chart Donation.group(payment: [{name: "Series A", data: true}, {name: "Series B", data: false} ]).group_by_day(:created_at).count, colors: ["#342F49", "#FB4D00" ] %>
```

But this time I get the error

> Arel::Visitors::UnsupportedVisitError in Dashboard#index
>
> Unsupported argument type: Hash. Construct an Arel node instead.

I have tried to make some research on how to construct an Arel node for this, but no success yet. Please I need some help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some help from a member on the **Reddit rails community**, and then figured out how to make it work.

The error is caused by the hash value that is being passed to `Donation.group`. This is an ActiveRecord method, not something provided by `Chartkick`, so it doesn't understand the name/data hashes that is being passed to it.

The order of operations needs to be inverted so that the **chartkick config** is passed to the `line_chart` function, and the SQL query parameters to ActiveRecord. It is also highly recommended to avoid database queries in the view layer, as that makes them almost impossible to test.

So here's how I fixed it;

Firstly, create a **charts_helper.rb** file in the **Helpers** folder of your application

**app/helpers/charts_helper.rb**

```
module ChartsHelper
  def donation_payments_chart_data
    [
      { name: 'true', data: Donation.group(:payment).group_by_day(:created_at).count, color: "#342F49" },
      { name: 'false', data: Donation.group(:payment).group_by_day(:created_at).count, color: "#FB4D00" }
    ]
  end
end
```

Secondly, in your views files, call the `donation_payments_chart_data` method defined in **app/helpers/charts_helper.rb**

**app/views/dashboard/index.html.erb**

```
<%= line_chart donation_payments_chart_data %>
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**